# Is it normal for other facebook users to not be able to use my app yet?

Tags: android, authentication, fragment

For https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate login tutorial, should this work for other facebook users too? I set my key hash up correctly and was able to facebook login with my account. However when my dad tried logging in with his facebook account, my app said that there was an invalid key hash. Is this normal or is there an error going on?

Comment: you need to enable the "do you want to make this app available to all users" button in settings page of your project dashboard. If it doesnot work tell me.

Comment: I looked in settings but didn't find anything. It should be under app restrictions right?

Comment: it should be under status and review or similar at the top of the page

Comment: Do you know how to resolve this issue? It says I need a valid contact email but I logged in with my facebook account which is attached to a valid contact email.

Comment: somewhere along the dashboard there is a email field you just need to fill it out. Fb will not fill it for you

Comment: on the dashboard? I control f email but found nothing. I go through the rest of the tabs

Comment: Thank you so much. I found it. It was in settings